# Querying XML document using Linq and adding the results into a listview

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following code, now I am getting the query output in a console windows without any issues but I would like to have it in a Listview. I am not sure how to do it.. :)

This is my XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Student>
 <Person name="John" city="Auckland" country="NZ" />
 <Person>
    <Course>GDICT-CN</Course>
    <Level>7</Level>
    <Credit>120</Credit>
    <Date>129971035565221298</Date>
 </Person>
 <Person>
    <Course>GDICT-CN</Course>
    <Level>7</Level>
    <Credit>120</Credit>
    <Date>129971036040828501</Date>
 </Person>
</Student>
```

And below is my code:

```
List<string> list1=new List<string>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path + "\\Student Data\\data.xml");

    //IEnumerable<XElement> rows = from row in xDoc.Descendants("Person")
    //                             where (string)row.Attribute("Course") == "BICT"
    //                             select row;
    string i = textBox1.Text;

    IEnumerable<XElement> rows = 
        xDoc.Descendants()
            .Where(d => d.Name == "Person" && 
                        d.Descendants().Any(e => e.Name == "ID" &&
                                                 e.Value == i)
            );

    foreach (XElement xEle in rows)
    {
        IEnumerable<XAttribute> attlist = 
            from att in xEle.DescendantsAndSelf().Attributes() 
            select att;

        foreach (XAttribute xatt in attlist)
        {
            string n = xatt.ToString();
            //Console.WriteLine(xatt);
            list1.Add(n);
        }
        foreach (XElement elemnt in xEle.Descendants())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(elemnt.Value);
            list1.Add(elemnt.Value);
        }
        //Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");

    }
    //Console.ReadLine();
    listView1.Items.Add(); // I am not sure.... 
}
```

Comment: I don't see any descendants of `Person` with name `ID`. Are you sure your query works fine? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It works in Console window shows the results correctly now I am trying to implement it in a form, trying to add the results into a listview..

Answer (score 0):

Adding items to a ListView at run time is covered here in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983548(v=vs.71).aspx

```
// Adds a new item with ImageIndex 3
listView1.Items.Add("List item text", 3);
```

If you don't have any images, just set the index to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Create `ListViewItems` to add results to `ListView`. `ListViewItem` accepts array of strings. First one is a text of item. Others are subitems (visible in Details view mode)

```
var items = from p in xdoc.Descendants("Person")
            select new ListViewItem(
                new string[] {
                    (string)p.Attribute("name"),
                    (string)p.Element("Course"),
                    (string)p.Element("Level")     
                }
                );

foreach(var item in items)
     listView.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: @raam030 How do you know that items are not in listview? Have you added columns to list view? Have you set view mode `Details`?

Comment: @raam030 make sure you not clear items collection after assigning it to listview. Set brake point in debugger to see if `items` collection is empty or not. If it is empty, then you have problems with your xml, otherwise something wrong with listview settings.